# Issues with image inside Bootstrap modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWGXKJ

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#modal" class="btn btn-primary">Open</a>
<div id="modal" class="modal modal-wide fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/aZO5Kol.jpg"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

1. How do I get the modal to expand its width to fit its containing image without having to calculate and use the image width in pixels.
2. How do I get a horizontal scrollbar, on the window itself, when the modal extends horizontally beyond the current view?

Answer (score 2):

1)
No need for pixels
You can do it with percentage %

```
img{
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Er... **How do I get the `modal to expand its width` to fit its containing image**. Not the image I guess. `:)`

Comment: The answer helped me, though, since I wanted to shrink the image to the modal's size... :)

Answer (score 1):

For all your questions, [**RTFM**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals):

> How do I get the modal to expand its width to fit its containing image without having to calculate and use the image width in pixels.

The class `.modal-dialog`. It has a default `width` of `600px`. Make it this way:

```
.modal {
  text-align: center;       /* Center the modal window. */
}

.modal-dialog {
  width: auto;
  margin: 30px auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

> How do I get a horizontal scroll bar when the modal extends horizontally beyond the current view?

This will make sure that, if the contents go out of the modal window range, it will show scrollbars.

```
.modal-dialog {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: First part works nicely but how would I get a scrollbar for the window itself - consider a very wide image: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZJLdW

Comment: @GaryIn Sorry went into a meeting... So yeah, give `modal-full` to make it work for you?

Comment: @GaryIn Check the second one. I doublechecked.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me. Could you try posting a codepen? I have also noticed it gives a horizontal window scrollbar by default for earlier bootstrap versions.

Comment: @GaryIn Add an image with the above stuff, and give me the codepen. I am definitely sure it should work.

Comment: Additionally try to add overflow-x: auto; to get horizontal scrollbar.